# Derivative of Multiplied Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have the equation $P = A\cdot B^{-t/T}$ where:

- $t$ is a variable scalar
- $A$ is a matrix in terms of $t$
- $B$ is a constant matrix
- $T$ is a known constant scalar

I need to determine the derivative of $P$ in terms of $t$. I (probably mistakenly) assumed the product rule applied such that $\dfrac{dP}{dt} = A\cdot (-t B^{-t/T -1}) + (B^{-t/T})\cdot \dfrac{dA}{dt}$.
but this does not provide the correct result when evaluated.

Is a solution even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the product rule, but you cannot change the ordering of the matrices, i.e.  $dP = A\cdot dB^{-t/T} + dA\cdot B^{-t/T}$

Comment: That's progress! Now how can I determine $\dfrac{dB^{-t/T}}{dt}$ ?

Comment: $dB^{-t/T} = -\frac {dt} {T}{\rm log}(B)\cdot B^{-t/T}$